# Read Sld Style in pyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, sld, pyqt, pyqt4

I am trying to set a layer's style using pyQGIS. My primary idea was to set the style from a string, but unfortunately I can only do it from a file. This code works as a charm:

```
        filename= QDir.tempPath() + "/style.sld"
        f = open(filename,'w')

        if os.path.exists(filename):

            f.write(style)
            f.close()
            ret=layer.loadSldStyle(filename)

            if ret:
                self.log(logging.DEBUG, "Style loaded")
            else:
                self.log(logging.DEBUG, "Style not loaded: " + errorMsg)

            os.remove(filename)
```

As you can see, I am writing the `style` string into a temporary file, loading the style and then removing it. **What I would like to do instead**, is to pass the string straight to the `readSld` function, which is wrapped in `loadSldStyle`:

```
        d = QDomDocument()
        ret=d.setContent(style)

        if ret:
            self.log(logging.DEBUG, "Document created")
        else:
            self.log(logging.DEBUG, "Document not created")

        self.log(logging.DEBUG, "content: " + d.toString())

        myRoot=d.firstChildElement
         ("StyledLayerDescriptor")

        if myRoot is None:
            self.log(logging.ERROR,  u"Could not get "
                "root element")
            return

        namedLayerElem=myRoot.firstChildElement
         ("namedLayerElem")

        if namedLayerElem is None:
            self.log(logging.ERROR,  u"Could not find "
                "NamedLayer")
            return

        errorMsg = str("")
        ret=layer.readSld(namedLayerElem,errorMsg)
```

Please note that this is very similar to the C++ code for the method `loadSldStyle` on the [QgsMapLayer](http://qgis.org/api/qgsmaplayer_8cpp_source.html) class implementation

The `QDomDocument` contains the correct style, and the `myRoot` and `namedLayerElem` nodes are correctly created. Nevertheless, `readSld` returns false, and worst of all, the error string is empty so I have no idea what is going on! 
Any advice on what might be the problem? I know that this function has been ported to sip.

Answer (score 1):

The readSld has the function signature

```
    
virtual bool    readSld (const QDomNode &node, QString &errorMessage)
```

So I dont see why your code should not work, maybe you could try the passing the root ???

```
layer.readSld(myRoot)
```

Comment: According to the implementation on the C++ code, you need to pass the "NamedLayer" element, not the top element "StyledLayerDescriptor"